# Confused by the STM32F101-LQFP48 power supply scheme in the datasheet

Tags: power, capacitor, pcb, pcb-design, pins

Recently I have started to learn about designing hardware with STM32. In the schematic side of the design, I got confused with the power supply scheme given in the datasheet since I have no prior knowledge about hardware design before. I have looked at two sources about this topic, which seemed a bit convoluted. The first source is obviously the datasheet and it looks like this:
[image]

This is fine up until the caution part below that says 4.7uF cap **must** be connected to VDD3 but the problem is the scheme shows the 100nF caps also have to be connected to all the VDD pins. Does that mean I have to connect a 100nF cap to each VDD# pin starting from the first and connect an additional series capacitor to the VDD3? But that would just create an open circuit for DC so that can't be it. If I am supposed to connect the 4.7uF cap parallel to the 100nF caps that wouldn't be connecting it to the VDD3 since all of the VDD pins are already parallel so I am just connecting another parallel 4.7uF to the 100nF caps which includes one 100nF for the VDD3 too or not? I also think by connecting the datasheet means physically connecting so that the 4.7uF will be closer to the VDD3 pin. That'll be great if anyone can enlighten me about this.

My initial attempt is this:
[image]

Comment: Make sure you place those decoupling caps immediately adjacent to the pins on the MCU which they serve, and route the traces for both Vdd & Vss *directly* to those pins (no long windy loops or vias).

Answer (score 5):

This is more of a note to board design than schematic design.

These capacitors are decoupling capacitors and are **essential** to the functioning of the chip to filter high frequency noise on the power rails.

> Does that mean I have to connect a 100nF cap to each VDD# pin starting from the first and connect an additional series capacitor to the VDD3?

Yes every Vdd/Vss pair requires a direct connection with a decoupling capacitor. According to ST's documents, of 100nF.
ST also recommends the 4.7 uF as a larger capacitor for lower frequencies.

Due to the lower frequency it typically does not matter on which Vdd/Vss pair the 4.7 uF is wired to.
However it looks like ST has found out during testing that it's best to hook it up to Vdd3/Vss3. Probably because a noisy internal peripheral is wired to Vdd3.

Vdda/Vssa requires a different decoupling because the clock system and analog domain is supplied by this.

*I'd suggest you dive into decoupling capacitors and their placements a bit more before you start routing the board.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes all 100nF caps must be at each supply and ground pin pair. The 4.7uF cap must at the specified supply pin in addition to the 100nF. The capacitors are in parallel, not in series.

Just look at example schematics of Nucleo boards or hardware getting started guide.